# I have an error in trying to load multiple components after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

In my application, the home page contains a form that creates workout objects. I am trying to do the same thing with meal objects, but on another page, and after clicking the "meals" button from my navbar, I get an error.
This is my navbar component where I click on the meals button.

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Link, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
import { AppBar, Avatar, Toolbar, Typography, Button} from '@material-ui/core';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import decode from 'jwt-decode';
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import useStyles from './styles';

const Navbar = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [user, setUser]=useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile')));
    const dispatch=useDispatch();
    const navigate=useNavigate();
    const location=useLocation();


    const logout=()=>{
        dispatch({type:'LOGOUT'});

        navigate('/');
        setUser(null);
    };

    const meals=()=>{
        dispatch({type:'MEALS'});
        navigate('/meals');
    };

    useEffect(()=>{
        const token=user?.token;

        if(token){
            const decodedToken=decode(token);

            if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < new Date().getTime()) logout();
        }

        setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile')));
    },[location])

    return (
        <AppBar className={classes.AppBar} position="static" color="inherit">
            <div className={classes.brandContainer}>
            <Typography component={Link} to="/" className={classes.heading} variant="h2" align="center">Workouts</Typography>
            </div>
        <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
            {user ? (
                <div className={classes.profile}>
                    <Avatar className={classes.purple} referrerPolicy="no-referrer" alt={user.result.name} src={user.result.imageUrl}>{user.result.name.charAt(0)}</Avatar>
                    <Typography className={classes.userName} variant="h6">{user.result.name}</Typography>
                    <Button variant="contained" className={classes.logout} color="secondary" onClick={meals}>Meals</Button>
                    <Button variant="contained" className={classes.logout} color="secondary" onClick={logout}>Logout</Button>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <Button component={Link} to="/auth" variant="contained" color="primary">Sign In</Button>
            )}
        </Toolbar>

        </AppBar>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

This is my single Meal component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardActions, CardContent, CardMedia, Button, Typography } from '@material-ui/core/';
import ThumbUpAltIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ThumbUpAlt';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import MoreHorizIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreHoriz';
import ThumbUpAltOutlined from '@material-ui/icons/ThumbUpAltOutlined';
import moment from 'moment';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

import useStyles from './styles';


import {deleteMeal, likeMeal} from '../../../actions/meals';


const Meal=({meal, setCurrentId})=> {
    const classes=useStyles();
    const dispatch=useDispatch();
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));

    const Likes = () => {
      if (meal.likes.length > 0) {
        return meal.likes.find((like) => like === (user?.result?.googleId || user?.result?._id))
          ? (
            <><ThumbUpAltIcon fontSize="small" />&nbsp;{meal.likes.length > 2 ? `You and ${meal.likes.length - 1} others` : `${meal.likes.length} like${meal.likes.length > 1 ? 's' : ''}` }</>
          ) : (
            <><ThumbUpAltOutlined fontSize="small" />&nbsp;{meal.likes.length} {meal.likes.length === 1 ? 'Like' : 'Likes'}</>
          );
      }
  
      return <><ThumbUpAltOutlined fontSize="small" />&nbsp;Like</>;
    };
  
  return (
   <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={meal.selectedFile|| 'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/194400/49531010-48dad180-f8b1-11e8-8d89-1e61320e1d82.png'} title={meal.category}/>
      <div className={classes.overlay}>
          <Typography variant="h6">{meal.calories}</Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2">{moment(meal.createdAt).fromNow()}</Typography>
      </div>
      {(user?.result?.googleId===meal?.creator || user?.result?._id===meal?.creator) && (
        <div className={classes.overlay2}>
        <Button style={{color:'white'}} size="small" onClick={()=>setCurrentId(meal._id)}>
          <MoreHorizIcon fontSize="medium"/>
        </Button>
      </div>
      )}
      <div className={classes.details}>
        <Typography className={classes.title} gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">{meal.name}</Typography>
      </div>
      <Typography className={classes.difficulty} variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">{meal.category}</Typography>
      <CardContent>
      <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">{meal.calories}</Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions className={classes.cardActions}>
        <Button size='small' color="primary" disabled={!user?.result} onClick={()=>{dispatch(likeMeal(meal._id))}}>
            <Likes/>
        </Button>
        {(user?.result?.googleId===meal?.creator || user?.result?._id===meal?.creator) && (
          <Button size='small' color="primary" onClick={()=>{dispatch(deleteMeal(meal._id))}}>
          <DeleteIcon fontSize="small"/>
          Delete
      </Button>
        )}
     
      </CardActions>
      </Card>
  );
}

export default Meal;

This is my Meals components that stands for all the Meal objects.

import React from 'react';
import {Grid, CircularProgress} from '@material-ui/core';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import Meal from './Meal/Meal';
import useStyles from './styles';

const Meals=({setCurrentId})=> {
    const meals=useSelector((state)=>state.meals);
    const classes =useStyles();
    
   
  return (
      !meals.length ? <CircularProgress/>:(
        <Grid className={classes.container} container alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
          {
            meals.map((meal)=>(
              <Grid key={meal._id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
                <Meal meal={meal}  setCurrentId={setCurrentId}/>
              </Grid>
            ))}
        </Grid>
      )
  );

  
}

export default Meals;
```

The error says "cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')" and length is in this component.

And, below I have my MealsForm which is the form used for creating the objects.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { TextField, Button, Typography, Paper } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import FileBase from 'react-file-base64';

import useStyles from './styles';
import { createMeal, updateMeal } from '../../actions/meals';

const MealForm=({ currentId, setCurrentId=()=>{} })=>{
    const [mealData, setMealData]=useState({
        category:'',name:'', calories:'',selectedFile:''
    });

    const meal = useSelector((state) => (currentId ? state.meals.find((meal) => meal._id === currentId) : null));
    const dispatch=useDispatch();


    const classes=useStyles();
    const user=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
  
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(meal) setMealData(meal);
    },[meal]);

    const clear = () => {
        setCurrentId(0);
        setMealData({   category:'',name:'', calories:'',selectedFile:'' });
      };

   
    const handleSubmit=async (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!currentId) {
            dispatch(createMeal(mealData));
            clear();
        } else{
            dispatch(updateMeal(currentId, mealData));
            clear();
        }
     
    };

    if (!user?.result?.name) {
        return (
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <Typography variant="h6" align="center">
              Please Sign In to add meals
            </Typography>
          </Paper>
        );
      }
  
    return(
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <form autoComplete="off" noValidate className={`${classes.root} ${classes.form}`} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Typography variant="h6">{currentId ? `Editing "${meal.calories}"` : 'Creating a meal'}</Typography>
            <TextField name="category" variant="outlined" label="Category" fullWidth value={mealData.category} onChange={(e)=>setMealData({...mealData, category:e.target.value})}/>
            <TextField name="name" variant="outlined" label="Name" fullWidth value={mealData.name} onChange={(e)=>setMealData({...mealData, name:e.target.value})}/>
            <TextField name="calories" variant="outlined" label="Calories" fullWidth value={mealData.calories} onChange={(e)=>setMealData({...mealData, calories:e.target.value})}/>
            <div className={classes.fileInput}>
                <FileBase
                    type="file"
                    multiple={false}
                    onDone={({base64})=>setMealData({...mealData,selectedFile:base64})}
                />
            </div>
            <Button className={classes.buttonSubmit} variant="contained" color="primary" size="large" type="submit" fullWidth>Submit</Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" size="small" onClick={clear} fullWidth>Clear</Button>
        </form>
        </Paper>
    );
}

export default MealForm;
```

Here I have the code for the actions on the meals object

```
 import { FETCH_ALL, CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE, LIKE } from '../constants/actionTypes';
    
    import * as api from '../api';
    
    export const getMeals=()=> async (dispatch)=>{
        try{
            const {data}=await api.fetchMeals();
    
            dispatch({type:FETCH_ALL,payload:data});
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    
    }
    
    export const createMeal=(meal)=>async(dispatch)=>{
        try{
                const {data}=await api.createMeal(meal);
    
                dispatch({type:CREATE,payload:data});
                console.log(data);
        }catch(error){
                console.log(error.message);
        }
    }
    
    export const updateMeal=(id,meal)=>async(dispatch)=>{
        try{
            const {data}=await api.updateMeal(id,meal);
    
            dispatch({type:UPDATE,payload:data})
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    
    export const deleteMeal=(id)=>async (dispatch)=>{
        try{
            await api.deleteMeal(id);
    
            dispatch({type:DELETE,payload:id});
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    
    export const likeMeal=(id)=>async(dispatch)=>{
        try{
            const {data}=await api.likeMeal(id);
    
            dispatch({type:LIKE,payload:data})
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Below I have the MealsPage component. The flow goes like this: Navbar, MealsPage, Meals, Meal

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Container,  Grow, Grid} from '@material-ui/core';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {getMeals} from '../../actions/meals';

import Meals from "../Meals/Meals";
import MealForm from "../MealForm/MealForm";
import useStyles from './styles';


function MealsPage() {
    const [currentId, setCurrentId]=useState(null);
    const classes=useStyles();
    const dispatch=useDispatch();

    useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(getMeals());
    },[currentId, dispatch]);

    const meals=getMeals();
    console.log(meals);
  return (
    <Grow in>
                <Container>
                    <Grid className={classes.mainContainer} container justifyContent="space-between" alignItems='stretch' spacing={3}>
                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={7}>
                            <Meals  setCurrentId={setCurrentId}/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                        <MealForm currentId={currentId} setCurrentId={setCurrentId}/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Container>
            </Grow>
  )
}

export default MealsPage
```

I cannot see the problem. Could you help me solve this?

Comment: It looks like at the beginning of your `Likes` component, where you check for `meal.likes.length > 0`, `meal.likes` is undefined. I would start by doing `console.log(meal)` before that check and looking at the log to see what the `meal` object looks like.

Comment: I tried some logs and I believe that it doesn't reach that point. The error occurs before that.

Comment: Ok, what line does the error occur?

Comment: The error occurs at this conditional statement:      !meals.length ? <CircularProgress/>:( which is in the Meals component. It cannot move on  to the Meal component. I updated the question with the MealsPage component as the user clicks the button in the navbar, enters the MealsPage component and then goes into the Meals component and lastly, into the single Meal component.

Comment: You can try changing that line to `!meals || !meals.length ? <CircularProgress/>:(`. This will first check that meals exists, then check the length. This will get rid of this specific error and help you progress.